# How to create constraint on attribute in table A which depends on attribute in table B?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I am trying to implement a constraint for an attribute in table `A` which depends on the value of an attribute in table `B`.

I was thinking this would work:

```
CREATE TABLE B (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Quantity INTEGER,
    ...,
);

CREATE TABLE A (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    OtherID INTEGER,
    Quantity INTEGER CHECK(Quantity > 0 
        AND Quantity <= 
        SELECT B.Quantity FROM B WHERE ID == B.ID)
);
```

When I run this I get an error around the `SELECT` statement. How can I enforce a constraint so that no row is added to table `A` where `A.Quantity > B.Quantity`?

Comment: You can use a trigger.

Comment: How would it work in this case?

Comment: You can't with a `CHECK`. From here [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) "Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row."